# Dissapear And Appear Admob AdView On User Activity and InActivity Android

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, android-event, android-gesture

I have a particular scenario where I want to hide the Admob AdView when the user has tapped the screen and show again after the 1 seconds of user inactivity on the application.

I have am successfully hiding the AdView and showing it again after user inactivity but the problem is:

I am detecting that either user tapped the screen or not through this method **onUserInteraction()**.

This method is working fine but when I **tap on the AdView itself**, the **AdView get hidden**.

Which should not happen. The normal behavior of AdView is that it should open **Intersticial Ad when tapping the AdView.**

How can I resolve this issue? or where should **I handle the Tap event of the user to decide wether the Ad should be hidden or intersticial Ad should be opened.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, [onUserInteraction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction%28%29) intercepts events on the entire activity before they get fired on the views.

Depending on your application, you may want to use [onTouchEvent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) and [onTrackballEvent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTrackballEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) to only consume events not handled by your views.  Or, alternatively, you could add event listeners to your views (not the `AdView`) to register for such events.